# Get closest points of a point from a DB

Tags: mysql, hibernate, mariadb, topology, jts

I use a MariaDB database where I store a huge amount of points (latitude and longitude) using Hibernate `jts.geom.Point` type. In the database is stored as `geometry` type.

I want to know how could I get the closest 10 points given a certain point. How could I do that using a SQL query? Or maybe a query and post-code in the backend.

Thanks!

Comment: A simple query can do this. Now, producing an efficient query is a different story.

Comment: @TheImpaler so how? Could you give an example?

Comment: Which version of MySQL or MariaDB?  st_distance_sphere() is not available in most versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can do:

```
create table t (loc point);

insert into t (loc) values
  (POINT(10, 0)), 
  (POINT(15, 20)),
  (POINT(50, 50));
```

Then you can find the closest two points to (49, 49):

```
select *,
  st_distance_sphere(loc, POINT(49, 49)) as dist
from t
order by st_distance_sphere(loc, POINT(49, 49)) 
limit 2 -- only the closest two points
```

Result:

```
loc              dist
---------------  -----------------
{"x":50,"y":50}  132584.0664606239
{"x":15,"y":20}  4416195.256674154
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i4qe5SKdxRSLFzqHYXvwTu/0).

Now, this works, but with millions of rows it won't be very efficient. You'll need to prefilter using "rectangles" or "areas", so an index can be of use.

**EDIT for MariaDB**

MariaDB's syntax is slightly different. See below:

```
select ST_AsText(t.loc) as point, 
  ST_Distance(loc, POINT(49, 49)) as dist
from t
order by ST_Distance(loc, POINT(49, 49))
limit 2;
```

Result:

```
point         dist
------------  ------------------
POINT(50 50)  1.4142135623730951
POINT(15 20)  44.68780594300866
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9da9978ee7b012f7b82446eeef8eabef).

Comment: It works on DB Fiddle, but in my MariaDB console it doesn't work :/

Comment: What version of MariaDB do you have?

Comment: MariaDB 10.4.13

Comment: I think ST_Distance is for plain map, not sphere map :(

Comment: @Ommadawn You are right. MariaDB does not implement sphere distance. For low latitudes ST_Distance() can produce almost equivalent results, though. Alternatively you could use the Haversine formula in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: How apply haversine formula over the clause?

Comment: MariaDB implements `SIN()`, `COS()`, `ASIN()`. You can write the formula as `ORDER BY <formula>`. The Haversine formula is explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance. Shouldn't look that ugly; and will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 5 algorithms, with differing complexity and performance.  Plus Haversine code.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql